# Chrome OS: will developer mode remove existing Ubuntu installation?

Tags: chromebook

I have installed Ubuntu on a Chromebook using Crouton. It all worked fine until recently. The computer crashed and I had to reboot. After reboot, I was not in developer mode anymore and can't open the shell, and thus can't boot Ubuntu. I am afraid of re-entering developer mode, because this supposedly wipes the hard drive. Will I lose the already installed Ubuntu if I re-enter developer mode?

Comment: This isn't actually a question about Ubuntu, but about Chrome OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you pressed Space button while crash happened and changed you back from Developer mode (although it could happen by itself because if SSD or HDD did not respond at boot Developer mode again gets disabled). You can try accessing shell using CTRL + ALT + Back or Forward if that does not work and you really need to retrieve Ubuntu chroot you need to unplug SSD and insert it into other Linux device,chroot is saved in /usr/local/chroot/

Comment: Indeed that is the problem. Man that stuff is poorly documented... I had no idea this would wipe the HD... thanks for the info!